# Unable to debug a nodejs app inside of docker

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, dockerfile, nodemon

I am trying my hands on debugging a Nodejs app from inside of Docker using Nodemon.

I can debug my app with Nodemon without Docker using Visual Studio Code's Auto Attach feature.

But when I build my docker image and start the container via npm run dev:docker:debug I get following log but debugger is not attached. It might be something with the volume but I am not able to figure it out...

```
Successfully built 857d9da57565
Successfully tagged app:dev
Creating docker_app_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_app_1
app_1  |
app_1  | > app@1.0.0 dev:debug /usr/src/app
app_1  | > nodemon --config nodemon.json --env=development
app_1  |
app_1  | [nodemon] 2.0.2
app_1  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
app_1  | [nodemon] watching dir(s): src/**/*
app_1  | [nodemon] watching extensions: ts
app_1  | [nodemon] starting `cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect=0.0.0.0:5858' ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src --env=development`
app_1  | Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:5858/k3h42h4-h49d-4f00-adj877-60f6731548787
app_1  | For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
app_1  | Service started at ports:3000
```

**Folder structure**

```
App
|-- docker
|   |-- docker-compose.yml
|   |-- Dockerfile
|   `-- .dockerignore
|-- nodemon.json
|-- package.json
|-- tsconfig.json
|-- tslint.json
`-- src
    `-- index.ts
```

**index.ts**

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; // default port to listen

// define a route handler for the default home page
app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Hello worlds!");
});

// start the Express server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Service started at ports:${port}`);
});
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: app:dev
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ../src:/usr/src/app/src/
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev:debug" ]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API to receive data",
  "author": "Nikhil Gupta",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon.json --env=development",
    "dev:docker:debug": "docker-compose -f ./docker/docker-compose.yml up --build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.5.4",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.21",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  }
}
```

**nodemon.json**

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["src/public"],
  "inspect": true,
  "exec": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect=0.0.0.0:5858' ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src"
}
```

Comment: You forgot to open 5858 port at docker-compose

Comment: @ykit9 good catch but still not working... If I hit the endpoint nothing happens in terms of debugging in VS code and I get the response.

Comment: I may assume the debugger it not attached automatically, because vs code automated attachment is somehow configured to catch a node-inspect calls inside of an operating system, and it cannot reach the insides of the docker container. 
You can try to manually attach the debugger to a certain port.

Comment: @ykit9, thanks. It works now... But If I change something in the code it doesn't trigger a restart by nodemon... Any idea whats missing...

Comment: The fs events is not triggers on the mounted volumes as it supposed to in order the fs watcher to work. 
Here's the Windows solution for this:
https://forums.docker.com/t/file-system-watch-does-not-work-with-mounted-volumes/12038/10

The whole topic is also worth reading. 
In the past, I've tried to achieve the same thing as you, but ended up launching the development app on the host OS, because the debugger was sloppy and tweaking is not really helpful - the nodemon process takes some time to restart. But, who knows, probably the things has changed for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @ykit9 I did following

1) Added port 5858 into my docker-compose.yml

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: app:dev
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 5858:5858
    volumes:
      - ../src:/usr/src/app/src/
```

2) Added following configuration in VS Code's launch.json file.

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to Docker",
    "protocol": "auto",
    "port": 5858,
    "restart": true,
    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
    "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app/src"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the debugger is listening on port 5858 inside the container, you need to bind it to a port on the host machine if you want to connect to it from outside the container similar to how you have done for port 3000 in your compose file.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: app:dev
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 5858:5858
    volumes:
      - ../src:/usr/src/app/src/
```

Comment: i tried this but still not working... If I hit the endpoint, nothing happens in terms of debugging in VS code and I get the response and also it should restart nodemon when I change something but thats also not happening.